# Attribute in a Class is not found

Tags: python, object, tkinter

In this code:

```
class ButtonBox(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        shift = tk.Frame(self)
        shift.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

        shiftLabel = ttk.Label(shift, text = "Shift:")
        shiftLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        amountShift = ttk.Entry(shift, width = 5)
        amountShift.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

        encryptButton = ttk.Button(self, text = "Encrypt")
        encryptButton.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

        decryptButton = ttk.Button(self, text = "Decrypt")
        decryptButton.grid(row = 0, column = 3)
class MainWindow(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.model = Model()


        self.UserIO = TextIO(self)
        self.UserIO.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.Buttons = ButtonBox(self)
        self.Buttons.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        self.Buttons.encryptButton.config(command =  self.model.encrypt)
        self.Buttons.decryptButton.config(command =  self.model.decrypt)


    def Encrypt():
        message = self.UserIO.inputString.get()
        shift = int(self.Buttons.shift.get())
        self.model.encrypt(message, shift)

    def Decrypt():
        message = self.UserIO.inputString.get()
        shift = int(self.Buttons.shift.get())
        self.model.decrypt(message, shift)


root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(width = False, height = False)
MainWindow(root).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I create a MainWindow(), and then add a command to a Button in a Button object. However, it creates an error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Code Projects/Caesar Cipher.py", line 120, in <module>
    MainWindow(root).pack()
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Code Projects/Caesar Cipher.py", line 103, in __init__
    self.Buttons.encryptButton.config(command =  self.model.encrypt)
AttributeError: 'ButtonBox' object has no attribute 'encryptButton'
```

, why does this happen? I created a ButtonBox object, so I do not understand why this does not work.

Comment: It doesn't work because `ButtonBox` has no attribute `encryptButton`.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Can you please show the code for button box as well.

Comment: Mabel you have spelled the encrypt button differently in the button box than you have here?

Comment: Also, can you please include the full error message.

Comment: @JonahFleming Okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `self.encryptButton` in `ButtonBox.__init__` instead of just `encryptButton`. You created a local variable `encryptButton` within the `__init__` function, which is not not accessible externally.

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    …
    self.encryptButton = ttk.Button(self, text = "Encrypt")
    self.encryptButton.grid(row = 0, column = 2)
    …
```